# Popular posts - based on pageviews

Tags: plugin-jetpack, google-analytics, popular-posts

I'm trying to figure out if it's possible, either by using a pre-existing plugin or some other route to pick the 10 most popular posts based off of page views (per the last month)? Using either Google Analytics or WordPress.com stats. I'm really stuck with this, if there's an API that would point me in the right direction, or a plugin that stores all the pageviews locally that I could access.

I just found this: [Popular posts by view with Jetpack](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/95847/popular-posts-by-view-with-jetpack)

But does anyone know how to add the date scope to something like this?

Comment: I just found this, which helps, but doesn't have enough info or posts, or just posts..

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9910791/how-to-query-the-number-of-view-counts-for-a-post-in-wordpress-jetpack/13481345#13481345

Comment: Whats the date scope?

Comment: I'm trying to retrieve the most popular post from the last month