# How to display most popular post by views count in WordPress?

Tags: query-posts, views

I tried to display the most view post in last 30 days in my WP page, how to do this?

What I did is:

```
<div>Most Read Blog Posts Over Past 30 Days</div>
                            <?php
                                function filter_where($where = '') {
                                    //posts in the last 30 days
                                    $where .= " AND post_date > '" . date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-30 days')) . "'";
                                    return $where;
                                }
                                add_filter('posts_where', 'filter_where');

                                query_posts('post_type=post&showposts=15&meta_key=views&orderby=meta_value_num&order‌​=desc');

                                while (have_posts()): the_post(); ?>

                                <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php printf(esc_attr('Permalink to %s'), the_title_attribute('echo=0')); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>

                                <?php
                                endwhile;
                                wp_reset_query();
                                ?>
```

But it seem not working, the page present empty.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Popular posts by view with Jetpack](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/95847/popular-posts-by-view-with-jetpack)

Comment: Don't use query_posts.

Comment: still no luck, if I change the query to query_posts('post_type=post&posts_per_page=10&orderby=comment_count&order=DESC'); the age display it. But this is based on comment :(